# How to disable % in the condent editable box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

How to disable `%` in the content editable box so that the user can not change it. I have a table which has a content editable box in `td`. When the user enters value in it, the `%` symbol should not be affected and has to be disabled. How to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
   <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm" id="t02">
      <thead style="text-align:center">
         <tr>
            <th class="col-md-6" style="text-align:center">Discounts</th>
            <th class="col-md-1"></th>
            <th class="col-md-1"></th>
            <th class="col-md-2" style="text-align:center">%</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th>XXX</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right" id="xxxDiscount">0.00%</td>
         </tr>
         <tr  class="active">
            <th>YYY</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
              <select id="pip-list">
              <option value=""></option>
              </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
          <tr class="active">
            <th>ZZZZ</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
              <select id="abc-list">
              <option value=""></option>
              </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr  class="active">
            <th>Discount</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right" id="discount" contenteditable="true">
              0%
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th style="color:blue" style="text-align:right">Total Discount</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right" id="secondTableTotal">
              0.00%
            </td>       
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </html>
```

[image: content editable box in td]

Using css after property adds an extra line in td while I am trying to change the value. Figure is attached

```
#discount::after {
    content: '%';
}
```

[image: fig2]

Fiddle output
[image: Fiddle output]

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use `:after` in css.

```
#discount::after {
    content: '%';
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrk8a5h9/1/)

Comment: The above adds an extra line in the content box

Comment: Please see the screen shot in the question

Comment: it works for me: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/qrk8a5h9/). Can you see it properly in the link?

Comment: Not working for you also. Adds an extra line in fiddle also. Edited the question with fiddle output

Comment: What browser are you using (name + version)?

Comment: Firefox browser. Version 45.0.2

Comment: Works only in chrome. Not in safari and firefox

Comment: I got the same version of firefox and it looks good for me. Maybe you changed some default configuration? Here is [my screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uoHaY.png)

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome, firefox and IE, could the problem be that you used <Style> instead of <style> for your tag?